# Envió de datos adjuntos con sendgrid

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo un código y no le consigo sentido a el error, quiero enviar un correo con sendgrid a través de unos datos de envió, es decir en un *json* me llega todo lo relacionado con el envió y el dato adjunto, el correo se envía bien el problema esta cuando le quiero adjuntar un dato.

Aquí el código:

```
if (options.attachments != undefined) {
    var filex = options.attachments[0].filename;
    var typex = options.attachments[0].contenType;
    attachment = FS.readFileSync(filex).toString("base64");

    message.attachments = [
        {
            content: attachment,
            filename: filex,
            type: typex,
            disposition: "attachment"
        }
    ];
}

console.log('option completo', options.attachments);
SGmail.send(message)
```

En `options.attachments` viene todos los datos, el archivo adjuntar, el tipo etc...**NO HAY MANERA QUE ENVIE ESO**... ahora cuando le doy una ruta estática al FS si lo envía, el código así funciona:

```
if (options.attachments != undefined) {
    var filex = options.attachments[0].filename;
    attachment = FS.readFileSync('HOME/DOCUEMNTOS/ARCHIVO.PDF').toString("base64");

    message.attachments = [
        {
            content: attachment,
            filename: filex,
            type: typex,
            disposition: "attachment"
        }
    ];
}

console.log('option completo', options.attachments);
SGmail.send(message)
```

De la manera envía el correo sin problema, el problema es que hay varias funciones que utilizan esta función y debo utilizar los datos que vienen.

No consigo el error por favor si pueden ver la falla de antemano gracias.

Comment: Podrías hacer un log del filename? aunque no entiendo el porque message.attachments es un array y no simplemente un objeto, pero me imagino que no tiene nada que ver con tu problema.

Comment: filename:'archivo.pdf' los datos lo trae bine

Comment: Me parace que el problema es que no es una ruta especifica... Utiliza path.join para unir la carpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo con el nombre del archivo. Por ejemplo `const { join } = require('path') fs.readFileSync(join('home/documentos/', filex)).toString("base64");`

Comment: es justo lo que creo, el problema es que a esta funcion le envia el archivo a adjuntar y no se como crearle la ruta...disculpe estoy comenzando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comenté antes el problema es porque fs necesita rutas absolutas para obtener los archivos, y como comentaste el nombre de tu archivo es `archivo.pdf` pero esto no es una ruta en todo caso puede ser interpretado como una ruta relativa, pero como no existe, falla la lectura. para evitar esto siempre debes especificar un ruta donde efectivamente existe el archivo.

Para facilitar esto node tiene path que contiene varias funciones para resolver y unir rutas.

En este caso para encontrar tu archivo que al parecer está en la carpeta documentos podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
const { join } = require('path') 
...
let file = fs.readFileSync(join('home/documentos/', filex)).toString("base64");
```

Join toma todos los parametros (paths) que le pasas y los une, si quisieras leer un archivo en el directorio de tu app podrias usar __dirname:

```javascript
const { join } = require('path') 
...
let file = fs.readFileSync(join(__dirname, filex)).toString("base64");
```

En el directorio donde se esta ejecutando la app con process.cwd:

```javascript
const { join } = require('path') 
...
let file = fs.readFileSync(join(process.cwd(), filex)).toString("base64");
```

Lo que debes tomar en cuenta es que independientemente de en donde se encuentre tu archivo este tiene que existir si o si en el directorio. Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.